# Insertar una imagen en Laravel

Tags: laravel

Soy nuevo en Laravel y estoy batallando en insertar una imagen que tengo guardada dentro de una carpeta.

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
<img src="{{ asset('img/logo.jpg') }}" width="50" height="50" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="">
</a>
```

La imagen se encuentra dentro de la carpeta resources/img/logo.jpg -> nombre de la imagen.

He intentado:

```
asset('img/logo.jpg')
URL::asset('img/logo.jpg')
entre otras y me sigue devolviendo un error 404.
```

Comment: Intenta crear tu carpeta: "img" dentro de la carpeta public y luego has tu llamada: {{ asset('img/logo.jpg') }}